# Is it possible to list all nicknames used for a specific IP address on IRC?

Tags: irc

Is it possible to list all nicknames used or has been logged in with, for a specific IP address on IRC?

Comment: That would depend on your access and the IRCD that is being used. Historic information is rarely available, current logins would possibly depend on additional service and/or operator access on public IRC networks. You could visit the help channel of whatever network you're using and ask there, they should be able to assist - assuming they support it.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Well, it kiiinda depends on the network; and whether you're asking as a network user or as staff member. But the answer in most cases is still no: most IRC servers are not configured to keep that sort of logs at all, and neither does the services software.

If the IRC server *is* configured to keep detailed logs of everything, you still wouldn't be able to access it *over* IRC – you'd have to access the files directly on the server.